# How to get a list of people with most common traits for each person in Python?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe which looks like (below 1 represents having a trait and 0 represents not having it):

```
Person Trait_1 Trait_2 Trait_3 Trait_4   
A        1       1       1     1
B        0       1       1     0
C        0       1       0     0
D        1       1       0     1
E        0       0       0     1
```

I want a function which returns, for each person, the top 10 people with the most number of common traits.

So for person A the output can be:

```
D (3 traits), B (2 traits), C(1 trait), E(1 trait)
```

I thought having a matrix which looks like encodes how many traits each person has in common with the other would be a good start:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
A  4  2  1  3  1
B  2  4  1  1  0
C  1  1  4  1  0  
D  3  1  1  4  1
E  1  0  0  1  4
```

But I am not sure how to achieve this or what this is called.

Comment: Do you have separate dataframes for each person?

Comment: @IoaTzimas No, there is one dataframe for all the people with columns showing if they have a trait or not.

Comment: Ok, the Traits in columns are somehow connected with persons? How do you connect the person in a row with other persons?

Comment: @IoaTzimas If a trait is 1 for a person, then the person has the trait. So I want, for each person, a list of persons with the most number of common traits.

Comment: Are you considering "lack" of a trait common?  You seem to be doing so when you compare E to E and score it a 4, but in C to E you score it a zero, which is contrary to that schema?  If you only want to look for "common 1's" that's going to be more straightforward...

Comment: @AirSquid E has only one trait, Trait_4. C does not have this trait, so they have 0 traits in common. E has 4 traits in common with itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# if not done already
df.set_index("Person", inplace=True)

res = (df@df.T).stack().reset_index(level=1)

res = res.loc[res["Person"].ne(res.index) & res[0].gt(0)].sort_values(0, ascending=False).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: list(x.values))
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

Person
A    [[D, 3], [B, 2], [C, 1], [E, 1]]
B            [[A, 2], [C, 1], [D, 1]]
C            [[A, 1], [B, 1], [D, 1]]
D    [[A, 3], [B, 1], [C, 1], [E, 1]]
E                    [[A, 1], [D, 1]]
dtype: object
```

And your function (results are in descending order):

```py
>>> res.loc['C']

[array(['A', 1], dtype=object), array(['B', 1], dtype=object), array(['D', 1], dtype=object)]
```

Comment: Thanks it works. This also returns people with no traits in common, is there a way to filter for people who have atleast one trait in common?

Comment: Yup, I tweaked my answer - see now

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [0, 1, 1, 0],
                        [0, 1, 0, 0],
                        [1, 1, 0, 1],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1]],
                 index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',],
                 columns=['Trait_1', 'Trait_2', 'Trait_3', 'Trait_4'])
```

2. Using matrix multiplication create the matrix of common traits (the one you described)

```
common_traits = df @ df.T
```

3. For each person print the string you want (top10 people with most traits in common)

```
n = 10
for index, row in common_traits.iterrows():
    top10 = row.drop(index).nlargest(n)
    top10 = top10[top10 > 0]
    string = ', '.join(top10.index + top10.map(lambda x: f' ({x} trait{"s" if x != 1 else ""})'))
    print(f'{index}: {string}')
```

#### Output

```
A: D (3 traits), B (2 traits), C (1 trait), E (1 trait)
B: A (2 traits), C (1 trait), D (1 trait)
C: A (1 trait), B (1 trait), D (1 trait)
D: A (3 traits), B (1 trait), C (1 trait), E (1 trait)
E: A (1 trait), D (1 trait)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to filter for people who have atleast one trait in common?

Comment: could you please clarify on you request with an example?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. Basically it would make sense if people with 0 traits in common do not show up

Comment: you mean instead of `E: A (1 trait), D (1 trait), B (0 traits), C (0 traits)` you want this output `E: A (1 trait), D (1 trait)`?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do it without an `iterrows` somewhere,
first get the matrix you talk about (`A*A.t`) then get the top columns for each row with `nlargest` (and remove the diagonal as you don't want to count a person as its closest neighbour)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

NB_MOST_SIMILAR = 3

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'t_1': [1,0,0,1,0], 't_2': [1,1,1,1,0], 
          't_3': [1,1,0,0,0], 't_4': [1,0,0,1,1]},
    index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
)

prod = df.dot(df.T)
prod.iloc[[np.arange(prod.shape[0])]*2] = 0

common_traits = dict()
for person_name, com_traits in prod.iterrows():
    traits = [
        (neighbour, traits) for neighbour, traits 
        in com_traits.nlargest(NB_MOST_SIMILAR).items()
        if traits > 0
    ]
    common_traits[person_name] = traits

common_traits
# {'A': [('D', 3), ('B', 2), ('C', 1)],
#  'B': [('A', 2), ('C', 1), ('D', 1)],
#  'C': [('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('D', 1)],
#  'D': [('A', 3), ('B', 1), ('C', 1)],
#  'E': [('A', 1), ('D', 1)]}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Is there a way to show how many traits are in common along with this? For example, something like 'A':[ 'D' (3 traits), 'B' (2 traits)]

Comment: Sure, instead of getting only nlargest index you could also get its value!

Comment: @Thelonious Monk I've edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a linear algebra answer, but if you want the number of common traits between person A and person B for example, you evaluate the scalar product of you line vector of person A and line vector of person B (this only works because you matrix is a binary matrix).

I have no idea what framework/library you are using, but if you are using pandas, you can easily extract line vectors and convert them to numpy arrays then do the scalar product.